# Partial assignment of struct in C99+

Tags: c, c99, c11

Sorry for bad English.

Suppose the code (C99 or later):

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
} foo_t;

foo_t f = { .a = 1, .b = 2  };

f = (foo_t){ .b = 3 };
```

What is `f.a` now? Does C standard say anything about this?

I know that for partial *initialization* the standard guarantees all uninitialized members will be initialized to "appropriate zero" (`0` for integers, `0.0` for floating, `NULL` for pointers, etc.). But the last statement isn't initialization (as I understand), because `f` is already exists. I'm confused.

Comment: I certainly don't know what the standard says, but afaict, you're assigning to a newly created (anonymous) struct that is partially initialized. The assignment will copy all members, so `a` will be 0.

Comment: @user707650 I think you mean "you're assigning _from_ a newly created (anonymous) struct that is partially initialized", right?  And assigning from that partially initialized object _to_ f.

In other words the last line is creating a temporary foo_t with element a zeroed out, then assigning that to f. 

(Good catch! I initially assumed the last line would simply alter the field b in f...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Point 6 in section *6.5.2.5 Compound literals* of the C99 standard states:

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list.

The unnamed `foo_t` is partially initialized, by the same rules you mention.

The last statement is an *assignment*, but the compound literal is an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. Meaning the `unnamed.a` has value zero and `f.a` is zero after the assignment.

Answer (score 5):

In this expression:

```
f = (foo_t){ .b = 3 };
```

`(foo_t){ .b = 3 }` is a compound literal, that is, a lvalue of `foo_t` type, that is partially initialized. It's still partial initialization, so the same rule applies:

**C11 6.7.9/21:**

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

It's only after the compound literal is initialized that you assign it to `f`.

It's equivalent to this:

```
foo_t f = { .a = 1, .b = 2  };
foo_t c = { .b = 3 };
f = c;
```

If you weren't familiar with compound literals, [GCC has good documentation for it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).